# Replace ' and ( characters with special characters in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, jsp

I have a string I would like to display that is formatted like this:

```
("Cats"meow's, Jr.)
```

The problem is, I can't figure out a way to run this string in a replace() function in JavaScript because using either ( or ' or " will interfere with one of the special characters. The string comes from a JSP variable, ${displayName}. Here are some of the attempts that threw an 'Unexpected identifier' error:

```
var displayName = JSON.stringfy("${displayName}");
var displayName = "${displayName}".replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
var displayName = '${displayName}'.replace(/"/g, '&quot;'); 
var displayName = ${displayName}.replace(/"/g, '&quot;'); 
var displayName = (${displayName}).replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
```

None of the above works, try the string out, including the (. encodeURI doesn't seem to work either, and that's not useful since I want HTML escaped characters not URL.

Comment: 1) Obviously you need to quote it to have valid JS syntax. 2) You need to JS-escape it to create a valid JS string; this is where you're falling down. I'm not sure what issue you're referring to regarding capture.

Comment: Your problem isn't related to JavaScript. You have escape these string in JSP, not JavaScript.

Comment: displayName should be a variable containing text, why are you trying to convert the string to a variable name, or am I way off here ?

Comment: Use: `displayName = displayName.replace(/["']/g, '&quot;');`

Comment: Dave, I've tried all the above, plus encodeURI (although not useful). Always get the above error. @hindmost What is the class and method to escape into HTML characters in JSP?

Comment: Normally once the variable is assigned, isin't it used like like an  undecorated variable `displayName = displayName.replace()` ?

Comment: @hindmost I eventually went with replacing the string in JSP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually went with replacing the string with JSP since wrapping it in JS was not working without significantly more work. Here is the answer:

```
<c:out value="${displayName}" escapeXml="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to access a JSP variable inside a JavaScript context.

You could print the variable's content inside a hidden `div` like so:

```
<div id="displayName" style="display: none"><%= displayName %></div>
```

and then access it in JavaScript something like:

```
var displayName = document.getElementById("displayName").innerHTML;
```

and use it to make the needed replaces.